# Button with right image aligned x points from the right

Tags: ios, uibutton, swift2

I'm trying to create a button that looks like this:

[image]

So it has a border and a right imageview.

I subclassed UIButton like this:

```
class ButtonWithRightImage: UIButton {

    override func imageRectForContentRect(contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var imageFrame = super.imageRectForContentRect(contentRect)
        imageFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMaxX(super.titleRectForContentRect(contentRect)) - CGRectGetWidth(imageFrame)
        return imageFrame
    }

    override func titleRectForContentRect(contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var titleFrame = super.titleRectForContentRect(contentRect)
        if (self.currentImage != nil) {
            titleFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMinX(super.imageRectForContentRect(contentRect))
        }
        return titleFrame
    }
}
```

And I created my button as follows:

```
lazy var testButton: ButtonWithRightImage = {
   let button = ButtonWithRightImage(forAutoLayout: ())

    button.setTitle("Privacy", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.DarkBlue(), forState: .Normal)

    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grey().CGColor

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow"), forState: .Normal)

    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 0)

    return button
}()
```

Now my button looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the image is not aligned with 20 points from the right. 
I can't figure out how to do this. I'm using autolayout to display the button so I can't just modify the frames I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your ButtonWithRightImage class need modification to achieve output as per your requirement.

```
class ButtonWithRightImage: UIButton {

    override func imageRectForContentRect(contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var imageFrame = super.imageRectForContentRect(contentRect)
        imageFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetWidth(contentRect) - CGRectGetWidth(imageFrame)
        return imageFrame
    }

    override func titleRectForContentRect(contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var titleFrame = super.titleRectForContentRect(contentRect)
        if (self.currentImage != nil) {
            titleFrame.origin.x = CGRectGetMinX(super.imageRectForContentRect(contentRect))
        }
        return titleFrame
    }
}
```

Issue is you need to minus image width from `container width`. Instead of `container maxX` value.

Let me know if you have any comment on the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set imageEdgeInsets for button Like Below code:-

```
lazy var testButton: ButtonWithRightImage = 
{
   let button = ButtonWithRightImage(forAutoLayout: ())

    button.setTitle("Privacy", forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.DarkBlue(), forState: .Normal)

    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grey().CGColor

    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow"), forState: .Normal)

    button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .Left
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 280, 0, 0)

    return button
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 and above** solution based on [MinuMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39545487/3659227).

Furthermore, provision is added to set right padding for image and left padding for text from storyboard.

Also, have handled the text length so it should not overlap image.

```
class ButtonWithRightImage: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var imagePaddingRight: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var textPaddingLeft: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func imageRect(forContentRect contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var imageFrame = super.imageRect(forContentRect: contentRect)
        imageFrame.origin.x = contentRect.width - imageFrame.width - imagePaddingRight
        return imageFrame
    }

    override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect:CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var titleFrame = super.titleRect(forContentRect: contentRect)
        if (self.currentImage != nil) {
            titleFrame.origin.x = super.imageRect(forContentRect: contentRect).minX + textPaddingLeft
            if titleFrame.size.width > frame.size.width - (imageView?.frame.size.width)! - imagePaddingRight {
                titleFrame.size.width = titleFrame.size.width - (imageView?.frame.size.width)! - imagePaddingRight
            }
        }
        return titleFrame
    }
}
```